# if $(\{n\alpha\}-c)(\{n\beta\}-c)\ge 0,\forall n\in N^{+}$ then have $\{\alpha\}=\{\beta\}$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-approximation

The following question was asked by one of my students.He didn't know the conclusion was correct. I thought for a long time and felt right.Because we seem to be using  Kronecker theorem

It follows from Kronecker's density theorem stating that if $\theta$ is an irrational real number, $\alpha$ is a real number, and $\varepsilon>0$ is any positive real number, then there exist integers $h,k$ with $0<k$ such that
$$
|k\theta-h-\alpha|<\varepsilon.
$$

**Problem**:

> Suppose $c\in (0,1)$ and irrational numbers $\alpha,\beta$ are such that
>   $$(\{n\alpha\}-c)(\{n\beta\}-c)\ge 0,\forall n\in N^{+}.$$
>   Prove or disprove
>   $$\{\alpha\}=\{\beta\}.$$

Comment: If we assume $ \alpha \neq \beta $ for the sake of contradiction, then for the case when $ \alpha - \beta $ is irrational, we can see that $\{n(\alpha - \beta)\}$ is dense in $(0,1)$ and thus there exists suitable value of n for which inequality does not hold

Comment: not sure the argument is that straightforward since $\{n(\alpha - \beta)\}$ is $\{n\alpha\}-\{n\beta\}+{0,1}$ so it is not clear why apriori $\{n\alpha\}, \{n\beta\}$ must be on different sides of $c$ even if say $\{n(\alpha - \beta)\}$ is large; I think the result is true but it requires a formal proof and the comment above is not that

Comment: @Conrad if we set $\{n(\alpha -\beta)\}$ as arbitrarily close to 1 shouldn't they be on opposite sides of c? Sorry if I'm wrong.

Comment: not necessarily, because they can be actually close for example if $\{n\alpha\}=.5, \{n\beta\}=.50000001, \{n(\alpha -\beta)\}=.9999999$; only if $\{n\alpha\} \ge \{n\beta\}$ it is true that  $\{n\alpha\} - \{n\beta\}=\{n(\alpha -\beta)\}$ and apriori we cannot guarantee both conditions; Kronecker theorem works though if $\alpha, \beta,1$ are linearly independent over the integers since then $(\{n\alpha\}, \{n\beta\})$ are dense in the unit square

Comment: @Conrad in Niven's little book Diophantine Approximations, on page 31 we have Theorem 3.6, discussing linear dependence over the integers. If $a \alpha + b \beta = c$ with $\gcd(a,b,c)=1, $ then the $(\{ n \alpha \}, \{ n \beta \})$  lie on, and only on, those portions of the lines $ax+by=t$ with $t$ any integer, that lie in the unit square, but are dense thereon

Comment: So this solves completely the problem showing the result true unless $\alpha - \beta$ rational (since in all the other cases of linear dependency, the slope of the above lines is not $1$ hence at least one such segment will have points outside the squares where the inequality holds and the degenerate Kronecker approximation theorem in dimension 2 is good enough);

Answer (score 2):

We indeed must have $\{\alpha\} = \{\beta\}$. Otherwise, as the comments point out, we may assume $\alpha = \beta+\frac{p}{q}$ for some $p \ge 1,q \ge 2, \gcd(p,q) = 1$.

First assume $c > 1/q$. Take $0 < \epsilon < \min(1-c,\frac{1}{q})$ and $n \equiv p^{-1} \pmod{q}$ with $\{n\beta\} \in (c-\frac{1}{q},c-\frac{1}{q}+\epsilon)$, which we may do since $q\beta$ is irrational. Then $\{n\alpha\} = \{n\beta\}+\frac{1}{q} > c$.

If $c \le \frac{1}{q}$, then $c+\frac{1}{q} \le 1$. Take $0 < \epsilon < c$ and $n \equiv -p^{-1} \pmod{q}$ with $\{n\beta\} \in (c+\frac{1}{q}-\epsilon,c+\frac{1}{q})$. Then $\{n\alpha\} = \{n\beta\}-\frac{1}{q} < c$.